# Developing an Application for all OS versions

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application which includes different features as a part of it. My emulator API version is 26 with target SDK of 20 and minimum Android version of 4.2. but when I install the application on smartphone it gets stack and some of the features could not work except with mobiles that have Android version 7.0. What should I do in order to make it work in all smart phones?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices has ranged APIs across the world.
To make it work in all smartphones, it means you need to make sure that your app work with their API.

To do that gracefully (it's called *Backward Compatibility*), there's something called Android Support Library. Now, the min. version to use Android Support Library is Android 4.0 (API level 14). [Read the overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/)

**How to:**

You can setup `build.gradle` by setting your `minSdkVersion` to 14, and add Android Support Library to your dependencies. [Read more](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup)

And in your code, instead of using the Framework API, use `android.support.*` when possible. **For example:** use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.